# angularjs Responsive ( without browser refresh)

Tags: angularjs

I am using an external plugin called angular slick .
https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick
My requirement being I want 3 slides on desktop while only 1 on mobile . I dont want to use jquery for this
I have achieved that through my code , but the only problem is when I am resizing the browser , I have to force the browser to refresh to see my responsive changes . 
As mine is a Single page application , refreshing doesnt make sense . Can I achieve the same without refresh using some concepts of angular or something else .(Jquery not allowed) My html is below

```
<slick infinite=true slides-to-show={{itemToShow}} slides-to-scroll=3 class="slider multiple-items">  
<div style="background-color: red" ng-repeat="item in items">
 <h3>{{item}}</h3>
</div>
</slick>
```

main.js

```
angular.module('slickApp')
.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8]; $scope.itemToShow = 3;
var width = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;


window.onresize = function(event)
{
document.location.reload(true);
}


if ( width < 600)
{
$scope.itemToShow = 1;
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    if (width < 600) {
        $scope.itemToShow = 1;
    }
};
```

Just remove the `document.location.reload(true);` inside your `window.onresize` function then replace with the code above.

Hope this helps.